# Items repeated when applying grouping on ComboBox

Tags: wpf, combobox, datagrid, grouping

I have a datagrid populated with datagridrows and is grouped based on some property. The groups in datagrid have a combo box and each row(item) also has a combo box. The items within combo box are also grouped via some property. The combo box itemssource is bound to a viewmodel property.

Following is the code piece which is used for implementing combo box:

```
<ComboBox  SelectedItem="{Binding Path = UnitItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
           SelectedValue="{Binding Path = UnitItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"                                                      
           IsEditable="False"
           FontWeight="Bold"
           ItemTemplate="{StaticResource GridNameBinding}">
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="GroupUnitData"
                              Source="{Binding Path = Units}">
            <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="GroupName" />
            </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
    </ComboBox.Resources>

    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <Binding Source="{StaticResource GroupUnitData}" />
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>

    <ComboBox.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource GroupHeader}" />
    </ComboBox.GroupStyle>

    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction 
                        Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.UnitSelection, 
                                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding GroupNameText}">
            </i:InvokeCommandAction>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ComboBox>
```

The problem I am facing is that each combo box along group header has repeated values (equal to number of rows within that group).

Please suggest.

Comment: A tip to get more out of StackOverflow. When asking for help concerning some sort of "bug", try providing a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the bug. Your question will get a lot more attention.

Comment: Thanks. I'll surely follow this.